# How to create Dictionary with a value as Two dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

In python, it would look like that:

```
{"cookie_name1":{"value":"cookie_value1", "expiry":"123456"}}
```

I created

```
Dictionary < string,Tuple<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, int>>>
```

In C#, but i am not sure that's how i'm supposed to solve it. And also i dont even understand how to input into that - i am kinda new in C#. I spent time googling it, but haven't found solution.

Comment: Can you show what the input dictionary looks like (key/value types), and what the output dictionaries should look like? If you have a `Dictionary<string, string>` input, what output do you want (i.e. what are the rules for splitting it into two dictionaries)?

Comment: I want to work with it kinda like if it would be python. These cookies should be saved, and then restored to selenium cookies

Comment: Assume I don't know python. Also, what do you mean by "cookie"? The first snippet looks like a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`

Comment: [that](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html)

Comment: I would look to see if you should be using [System.Net.CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer?view=netframework-4.8) or [System.Net.CookieCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecollection?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values look like a collection of cookies.
If that's the case, I assume the "keys" of the "sub"-dictionaries are always the same.
Then I would create a class Cookie and store that in a dictionary:

```
    public class Cookie
    {
        public string value { get; set;}
        public int expiry { get; set;}
    }
    Dictionary<string, Cookie>
```

Answer (score 0):

c# is a strong typed language. Ideally, you should create objects, and give them explicit properties:

```
class Cookie
{
     [JsonProperty("value")]
     public string Value;
     [JsonPropery("expiry")]
     public DateTime Expiry;
}

var cookieJar = new Dictionary<string, Cookie>();

cookieJar.Add("cookie_name1", new Cookie
{
    Value = cookie_value1,
    Expiry = DateTime.Now
});


// With json.net you can simply use
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cookieJar);
```

Comment: Yea, but i am not using Json, I'm getting Cookie list from selenium

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Is it a string/JSON, that you need to convert into a structure you can read with .net?

Comment: Input is ReadOnlyCollection<Cookie>, Cookie is OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie class. I need to get all these cookies, serialize to json string, than deserialize to ReadOnlyCollection<Cookie> and something i can operate with Cookie one-by one.

Cookie impl: [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html)